# date range coverage

Tags: sql, date, range

I have two attendance tables:

Daily Summary:

```
Emp_id     | Name    | Sched        | Time_in    | Time_out
-----------+---------+--------------+------------+-----------
E123       | John    | 2019-09-02   | 2019-09-02 | 2019-09-02
E123       | John    | 2019-09-03   | 2019-09-03 | 2019-09-03
E123       | John    | 2019-09-04   |            |           
E123       | John    | 2019-09-05   |            |           
E123       | John    | 2019-09-06   |            |           
E123       | John    | 2019-09-07   | 2019-09-07 | 2019-09-07
```

Leaves Summary:

```
Emp_id     | Name    | TYPE            | FROM       | TO
-----------+---------+-----------------+------------+-----------
E123       | John    | Paid Time Off   | 2019-09-04 | 2019-09-06
```

I need help to combine these two tables to identify the empty time in and time out rows from the daily summary that would result that the employee was on leave.  I can grab both **From** and **To** columns to match into the daily summary; however, I don't have a date for the **2019-09-05** since the leave summary table is a date range.

EDITED:

Apologies, here is the result that I would like to get:

```
Emp_id     | Name    | Sched        | Time_in    | Time_out   | Leave
-----------+---------+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
E123       | John    | 2019-09-02   | 2019-09-02 | 2019-09-02 |
E123       | John    | 2019-09-03   | 2019-09-03 | 2019-09-03 |
E123       | John    | 2019-09-04   |            |            |Paid Time off           
E123       | John    | 2019-09-05   |            |            |Paid Time off                     
E123       | John    | 2019-09-06   |            |            |Paid Time off                     
E123       | John    | 2019-09-07   | 2019-09-07 | 2019-09-07 |
```

Comment: Cold you, based on the example data, describe what's your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, just edited my post.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a simple left outer join between the two, where the daily summary sched column is between the leave summary from and to columns (please,tell me those aren't real column names).

Something like:

```
select
dly.*,
lv.type
from
daily_summary dly
left join leave_summary lv
  on dly.emp_id = lv.emp_id
  and dly.sched between lv.from_date and lv.to_date
```